# Underline string in Adobe Lifecycle Designer

Tags: javascript, sap-basis, livecycle-designer, adobe-form

I am trying to underline text using javascript in an adobe form. My current script is:

```
var a = this.getField("options").value;
of (a == "a") {
 event.value = (" model a paragraph ... ");
```

How can I get the first line in the paragraph to be underlined ?

Comment: You might want to use css? Or is this not in the browser?

Comment: can´t you use CSS? p::first-line pseudo element would be great here

Comment: I am not an expert in adobe form. But adobe form does not seem to be browser related. There sould be no css support.

Comment: The code you have isn't even syntactically valid.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`underline`](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/11.0/DesignerScriptingRef/WS92d06802c76abadb-3e14850712a151d270d-7b36.2.html) attribute of node font property:

```
 xfa.resolveNode("data.MainPage.BillingReport.Invoices.DATA["+i+"].QUANTITY").font.underline = "1";
```